# Is it better to use the generate migration command to build a database table or is the generate model command better?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am learning rails and it seems that there are two ways to create a database structure.

One is to use rails g migration table name and then add columns within the migration file.

The other way seems to be to rails g model modelname columname:datatype.

Which is a more standard or better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use this if you already have model or you just need to create a migration

```
rails g migration CreateUsers email:string name:string
```

**db/migrate/20170609085241_create_users.rb**

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :email
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

But if you need to create model as well then, in that case, go with

```
rails g model User email:string name:string
```

This will create model and migration for you

```
invoke  active_record
create    db/migrate/20170609085241_create_users.rb
create    app/models/user.rb
```

**app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have to generate model then use command:

```
rails g model model_name column_name:datatype ...
```

it will create model and table as well

When you have to change anything in table like column_name, add/remove columns, etc then you can create migration like

```
rails g migration AddColumnToTable column_name:datatype ...
```